# Beautifulsoup : Unable to extract href with several conditions

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract every links with BeautifulSoup from the SEC website such as [this one](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000320193&type=8-K&dateb=&owner=exclude&start=0&count=40) by using the code from [this Github](https://github.com/alions7000/SEC-EDGAR-text). The thing is I do not want to extract every 8-K but only the ones matching the items "2.02" within the column "Description". So i edited the "Download.py" file and identified the following :

```
    while continuation_tag:
        r = requests_get(browse_url, params=requests_params)
        if continuation_tag == 'first pass':
            logger.debug("EDGAR search URL: " + r.url)
            logger.info('-' * 100)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'documentsbutton'}):   
            URL = sec_website + link['href']
            linkList.append(URL)
        continuation_tag = soup.find('input', {'value': 'Next ' + str(count)}) # a button labelled 'Next 100' for example
        if continuation_tag:
            continuation_string = continuation_tag['onclick']
            browse_url = sec_website + re.findall('cgi-bin.*count=\d*', continuation_string)[0]
            requests_params = None
    return linkList
```

I've tried to add another loop to match my regex but it doesn't work

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'documentsbutton'}):
    for link in soup.find_all(string=re.compile("items 2.02")):
        URL = sec_website + link['href']
        linkList.append(URL)
```

Any helps would be really appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the `tr` that encapsulates both the `a` tag and the `td` tag that contains the `items 2.02` text. Then find the url in the `tr` if the `td` actually contains the text `items 2.02`:

```
for link in soup.find_all("tr"):
    td = link.find('td', {'class': 'small'})
    if td:
        if 'items 2.02' in td.text:
            URL = sec_website + link.find('a', {'id': 'documentsbutton'})['href']
            linkList.append(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something more concise by using [css pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). The following looks for `td` child elements, of parent with class `tableFile2`, that have an adjacent sibling `td` (i.e. next column) which is both the third column (`nth-of-type`)  of the table and contains 2.02; from those tds it filters to the child `a` tags that have `id documentsbutton`.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs # version 4.7.1 +

base = 'https://www.sec.gov'
r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000320193&type=8-K&dateb=&owner=exclude&start=0&count=40')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # or html.parser
links = [base + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.tableFile2  td:has(+ td:nth-of-type(3):contains("2.02")) #documentsbutton')]
```